# MWAA to start and stop EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow, mwaa

I'm new to using the AWS managed Airflow service. I want to use Airflow to start an EC2 instance, make sure it's running, and then do some further work in the instance.

So far I have this dag below which is basically a copy of [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-amazon/4.0.0/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags/example_ec2.py).

This, however, fails every time and I'm not adept enough to know why?

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ec2 import EC2StartInstanceOperator, EC2StopInstanceOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.ec2 import EC2InstanceStateSensor

INSTANCE_ID = os.getenv("INSTANCE_ID", "instance-id")

with DAG(
    dag_id='example_ec2',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    tags=['example'],
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    # [START howto_operator_ec2_start_instance]
    start_instance = EC2StartInstanceOperator(
        task_id="ec2_start_instance",
        instance_id=INSTANCE_ID,
    )
    # [END howto_operator_ec2_start_instance]

    # [START howto_sensor_ec2_instance_state]
    instance_state = EC2InstanceStateSensor(
        task_id="ec2_instance_state",
        instance_id=INSTANCE_ID,
        target_state="running",
    )
    # [END howto_sensor_ec2_instance_state]

    chain(start_instance, instance_state)
```

Comment: Do you any log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to answer my own question in case anyone else finds this.

The line below doesnt work for whatever reason

```
INSTANCE_ID = os.getenv("INSTANCE_ID", "instance-id")
```

The alternative is to do the following

```
from airflow.models import Variable # import Variable

INSTANCE_ID = Variable.get("INSTANCE_ID") # get INSTANCE_ID
```

Make sure you have added INSTANCE_ID as a variable by going to Admin -> Variable.